# PHP Uploading issue Getting Error 0 but move_uploaded_file() is returning false

Tags: php

PHP Uploading issue Getting Error 0 but move_uploaded_file() is returning false.  When I print out $_FILES I get

```
Array ( [uploadedfile] => Array ( [name] => flashlog.txt [type] =>
text/plain [tmp_name] => /tmp/php0XYQgd [error] => 0 [size] => 3334 ) )
```

I'm using a basic html/php tutorial which leaves me to believe that it might be a server issue.  I check the php.ini and have upload_max_filesize:2M, post_max_size:8M.  So I'm really confused as I thought error of 0 told me that it was successful.

The code I'm using is

```
<?php

// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = 'Test/';

$target_path = $target_path. basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) 
{
 echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
 " has been uploaded";
} 
else
{
 echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
 echo print_r($_FILES);
}
?>
```

Comment: And what exactly is the code that gives you an error? BTW, please **indent your code by 4 spaces** to format it correctly.

Comment: Have you cranked up the error reporting level? If something's wrong with the destination, `move_uploaded_file` should issue a warning telling you what's wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`move_uploaded_file()` will also return false if it can't write to the target directory.

Most PHP code I see to handle uploads skips checking some major piece of the process. Upload code should do the following steps:

1. Check that `$_FILES[]` exists and the correct entry is populated.
2. Look in the `error` field to see if it got to the server at all -- a lot of code just checks that it's 0, which means it can't return any decent error to the user.
3. Be certain the destination where you need to move the file actually exists.
4. Call `move_uploaded_file()` to do the move - too many just do a file copy, which bypasses the security checks that `move_uploaded_file()` does.

These are discrete steps: as you seem to be seeing, the actual upload can succeed, yet `move_uploaded_file()` can fail. Your question assumes that if the latter failed, so did the former.

Oh yes: call `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $destination)`. Using `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']` won't work.

Comment: That's what I would have answered.  Check your file permissions.  Given that it is a move operation, you probably also need permission to remove it from the source directory.

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` won't have troubles removing the temp file because it's being called by the exact same process that created it as part of the upload. :-)

Comment: Ok So here comes a huge pile of newb the permissions were wrong Thanks everyone.

Comment: Oddly enough, permissions were the first thing I looked at when the upload didn't work. my problem was that I had `if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) { }`. Changing to `['tmp_name']` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I got same error in my project there is not any fault in your code but there is issue in file name like i can't upload image named ("IMAG0889.jpg", "IMAG0892.jpg", "IMAG0893.jpg" etc) it gave me error 0. after rename file like("Deep2.jpg", "IMG_20160925_093715_1.jpg") I successfully uploaded my image file. So ***try to upload file after rename it***.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line ----
$target_path = $target_path. basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

With these ----
$target_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/folder_name/'. $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

This works for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33901937)