# Upload file using PHP on OpenShift

Tags: php, file-upload, openshift, redhat

I'm trying to upload an image using the following code:

### index.php:

```
<form action="upload_photo.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>
        Upload a new photo to the server:<br/><br/><br/>
        <input type="file" name="myphoto"/><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload photo"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

### upload_photo.php:

```
// This function is included from another .php file
function checkUploadedPhoto() {
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["myphoto"]["name"]);

    if(isset($_FILES['myphoto']) AND $_FILES['myphoto']['error'] == 0) {
        // Check size
        if($_FILES['myphoto']['size'] <= 1000000) {
            // Get extension name
            $fileInfo = pathinfo($_FILES['myphoto']['name']);
            $upload_extension = $fileInfo['extension'];
            $allowed_extensions = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');

            // Check if the file already exists
            if (file_exists($target_file)) {
                echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
            }

            // Check if the file has a correct, expected extension
            if(in_array($upload_extension, $allowed_extensions)) {
                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myphoto']['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
                echo "error3";
        }
        else
            echo "error2";
    }
    else
        echo "error1";

    echo "<pre>". print_r($_FILES) ."</pre>";
    echo "Error code: " .$_FILES['myphoto']['error'] ."<br/>";
    return false;
}

if(checkUploadedPhoto()) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
else {
    echo "upload error";
}
```

### Browser result:

[image: Rendering]

Even though the error code is `0`, **the upload fails**. Is it a permission issue ? I can't seem to tell where is the issue from.

Other references I checked, didn't help though:

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305788/php-uploading-issue-getting-error-0-but-move-uploaded-file-is-returning-false) /
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707230/file-upload-results-in-file-size-0-and-error-code-0) /
[link3](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/516697?start=0&tstart=0) /
[W3Schools PHP upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

### EDIT:

This is my app's structure:

[image: Structure]

### UPDATE:

I added **this test** to check if the `uploads/` directory is **writeable**, & it turned out that it's **inaccessible**:

```
// This condition is true
if (!is_writeable('uploads/' . $_FILES['myphoto']['name'])) {
    die("Cannot write to destination file");
}
```

### UPDATE2:

I changed the **target directory** from `"uploads/"` to `"/uploads/"` & it worked on **localhost**, but not on the hosted server.

Comment: did you created the folder uploads just near the upload_photo.php ?

Comment: @RajeshJNair yes I did. I will update my answer with the **project's view**.

Comment: Have you looked in the error.log?

Comment: @JayBlanchard no I didn't, I don't know how to. Can you guide me through the process ?

Comment: Try writing `/uploads/` as dir instead, so takes the folder from root.

Comment: @JDev - Your log files should be located at `/var/log/` - if you're on a shared hosing, look somewhere before or in the `public_html` folder, file should be called `error_log`

Comment: @uruloke nothing changed...

Comment: @andre3wap how can I access the file in PHP code ? (supposing that it's located in `/var/log/` as you said)

Comment: Does it work on localhost?

Comment: @uruloke interesting theory, I haven't actually tried it on localhost. I will, right away.

Comment: @JDev, If you can get it to work local, then you know it's not the code that is wrong at least.

Comment: same result on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I had to change:

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
```

to

```
$target_dir = dirname(__FILE__) ."/uploads/";
```

`dirname(__FILE__)` refers to the **full path** and **filename** of the file.

Comment: Pride.

Several years ago I noticed that I would find the answer to a problem only after I had asked for help.  Something about the male psyche puts our determination and creativity into overdrive when the potential to be shown-up by another man exists.

:^)

Comment: Pride says not to ask for help...  Then (sometimes) provides the answer once help is on the way.  Ask for help a little sooner.  ;^)